# Does JS follow dynamic scope chain while looking up value of parameters

Tags: javascript

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(a); // 3（not 2！）
}

function bar() {
  var a = 3;
  foo();
}

var a = 2;

bar();
```

Now this I get that result is 2 because it follows the static scope chain to lookup value of  var a which
is determined in the global scope.

What I don't get is the code below

```js
function foo(a) {
    console.log( a ); // 3（not 2！）
}

function bar() {
    var a = 3;
    foo(a);
}

var a = 2;

bar();
```

Once I pass on parameters into foo, it seems like foo is looking up value of var a following dynamic scope chain.
Why is that?

Comment: I think you're looking for Javascript Hoisting  - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript

Comment: Try `foo(5)` instead of `foo(a)` in the `bar` implementation.

Comment: JavaScript scope is never dynamic.

Comment: Variables are scoped if you redeclare them inside functions. You can check variable hoisting to know how scope works for variables.

Answer (score 0):

When you call bar() and make the value of a 3, and use that variable as the parameter of foo() it returns 3. Because the last value you set is 3. a is 3 in the scope of bar() only. When you don't use a parameter or return that value, you don't export it out of the bar() scope. That means, out of bar(), a is 2.